# hi ... i had this error when run trying to call vgg16 model

Tags: python

```
error message :
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
the code :
VGG_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3))

for layer in VGG_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
VGG_model.summary()  #Trainable parameters will be 0
train_feature_extractor=VGG_model.predict(x_train)
```

i tried to reduce the dimensionality of input data and its work but this effected on the Accuracy
so i run the code on cpu only and this work too but take a long time

Answer (score 1):

This error message is indicating that your GPU does not have enough memory to load your data.

If you want to use your GPU, you need to be sure that your data (batch) fits into its memory. Unfortunately, you do not provide additional information about your data preprocessing and the shape of `x_train`.

If `x_train` is a set of multiple images, a default batch size of 32 will be used.
Try to manually reduce the batch size by calling `VGG_model.predict(x_train, batch_size)` with setting the additional argument `batch_size` to a value smaller than 32.

[Tensorflow Documentation: predict()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict)

maybe this might be helpful as well:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666010/out-of-memory-when-extracting-training-images-features-from-vgg16-pretrained-mod)

Comment: x_train shape is 15000x128x128x3

Comment: i just reduced the batch size but the same problem remain